# adding two pandas dataframe value only if the row and column value is the same

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes with different sizes where one is bigger than the other but the second data frame has more columns.

I'm having problems with trying to add a data frame if it has the same column & row value as the other data frame which in this case is id

this is some dummy data and how I was trying to solve it

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame([(1,2,3),(3,4,5),(5,6,7),(7,8,9),(100,10,12),(100,10,12),(100,10,12)], columns=['id','value','c'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([(1,200,3,4,6),(3,400,3,4,6),(5,600,3,4,6),(5,620,3,4,6)], columns=['id','value','x','y','z'])
```

so if id of the `df1` and `df2` are the same then add the column value by the value in "whatToAdd"

data

```
df1: 
         id    value    c     
         1     2        3     
         3     4        5     
         5     6        7
         7     8        9     
         100   10       12    
         100   10       12
         100   10       12
df2: 
         id    value    x     y    z
         1     200      3     4    6
         3     400      3     4    6
         5     600      3     4    6
         5     620      3     4    6
```

expected:

```
  Out: 
     id    value    x     y    z
     1     202      3     4    6
     3     404      3     4    6
     5     606      3     4    6
     5     626      3     4    6
```

tried:

```
for each in df1.a:
    if(df2.loc[df2['a'] == each]):
        df2['a']+=df['a']
```

spew out an error "The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()." which confusing for me cause i tried:

```
df2.loc[df2['a']==1
```

out of the loop and it works

Comment: What is about column c in your example?

Comment: @Sören not using it at all just there for dummy that so that it similar with my real data environment :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you set both data frames to have same index:

```
df1 = df1.set_index("id")
df2 = df2.set_index("id")
```

You can do one *very simple* operation:

```
mask = df1.index.isin(df2.index)
df2["value"] += df1.loc[mask, "value"]
```

Output:

```
    value   x   y   z
id              
1   202     3   4   6
3   404     3   4   6
5   606     3   4   6
5   626     3   4   6
```

You can always do `df2.reset_index()` to get back to original setting.

Answer (score 1):

You can using `set_index` with `add`, then follow with `reindex`

```
df1.set_index('id').add(df2.set_index('id'),fill_value=0).dropna(axis=0).reset_index().reindex(columns=df2.columns)
Out[193]: 
   id  value    x    y    z
0   1  202.0  3.0  4.0  6.0
1   3  404.0  3.0  4.0  6.0
2   5  606.0  3.0  4.0  6.0
3   5  626.0  3.0  4.0  6.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is code I came up with. It uses a dict to look up the value for each id in df1. Map can then be used to look up the value for each id in df2, creating a series that is then added to df2['value'] to produce the desired result.

```
df1_lookup = dict(df1.set_index('id')['value'].items())
df2['value'] += df2['id'].map(lambda x: df1_lookup.get(x, 0))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a one-liner.

```
df2.loc[:, 'value'] += [df1.set_index('id').loc[i, 'value'] for i in df2.id]
print(df2)
>>>
   id  value  x  y  z
0   1    202  3  4  6
1   3    404  3  4  6
2   5    606  3  4  6
3   5    626  3  4  6
```